# c++ STL min_element

Tags: c++, stl

I want to find the minimum element in an array, but if the minimum element appears more than once, then I want the last occurrence of the element. I used `std::min_element()` with my `comp()` function.

```
vector<int>::iterator it=min_element(input.begin(), input.end(),comp);
cout << *it << endl;
cout << distance(input.begin(), it);

bool comp(int a, int b) {
if (a <= b)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

This code is giving an error saying invalid comparator on input  3 3 4.

Comment: Just apply `min_element` over reverse iterators; you'll get last occurrence for free.

Comment: `comp` does not satisfy the requirements of a strict weak ordering. Your program therefore exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: `if (a <= b)` -- `std::min_element` wants to know if `a < b`, not if  `a <= b`.  Your code answers the wrong question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie looking into possible implementations it should actually work, but it does not satisfy Compare requirement. Interesting question was it a good idea to put this requirement for comparator in this case

Comment: @Slava _"looking into possible implementations it should actually work"_ Dangerous thinking. Just the other week I had to dispel this when someone thought a broken comparator should be fine due to how they would personally implement stable_sort! Naturally it was crashing. Always code to the contract, period!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I understand that and I do not recommend to use broken comparator in this case. My question is - was it really necessary to put this requirement as almost any reasonable implementation would work with `<=`

Comment: @Slava Yes, it is necessary, because otherwise you add a constraint "make every implementation work with `<=`" and then you have the same problem in reverse: "why is it not `<`?" This makes it tougher to do equivalence with the comparator too

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I do not add a constraint, question was when it was designed they blindly chosen this concept as it was already there as strict weak ordering not really necessary here. And you do not need equivalence in this case.

Comment: @Slava Not blindly, there are good reasons, one of which I have laid out. Just because you do not need equivalence "in this case" doesn't mean you don't want it in other cases and who wants to define loads of different kinds of comparators? For further discussion you could ask a question "why was < chosen for stdlib comparators" but I suspect it's already been covered

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit why should I care about other cases? For example `std::unique` does not require strict weak ordering but it could, why "who wants to define loads of different kinds of comparators" did not stop them in this case? Removing strict weak ordering req would make this function more generic

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit case with `std::unique` is particularly pesky, as you usually sort before using it and you have to use 2 different comparators. Who cares, right?

Comment: @Slava Yeah that's a bit of a weird one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data are stored in a `vector`, then the use of a reverse iterator should suffice, as already suggested.

More generally, the Standard Library does not provide a `min_element_last` function, as also commented in [1](https://youtu.be/ezoEX4JcrgU?t=986). In this respect, a possible implementation of `min_element_last` may read:

```
template <typename I>
using ValueType = typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type;

template <typename I, typename R>
// I models ForwardIterator
// R models StrictWeakOrdering on ValueType<I>
I min_element_last(I first, I last, R cmp) {
    if (first == last) return last;
    I curr = first;
    ++first;
    while (first != last) {
        if (!cmp(*curr, *first)) {
            curr = first;
        }
        ++first;
    }
    return curr;
}

template <typename I>
// I models ForwardIterator
// ValueType<I> models TotallyOrdered
I min_element_last(I first, I last) {
    using T = ValueType<I>;
    return min_element_last(first, last, std::less<T>());
}
```

The advantage would be the possibility of using `min_element_last` also with iterators that only model the *ForwardIterator* concept.

Answer (score 3):

Give `min_element` reverse iterators instead:

```
vector<int>::reverse_iterator it=min_element(input.rbegin(), input.rend(),comp);
```

Then convert `it` back to a "normal" iterator *iff* you need to.

And don't forget to correct your comparator; it needs to be `<` not `<=`.

Comment: @RohitPandit Because that is not the meaning that is expected of your comparator. It can't just do "anything" it needs to do what the standard expects.

Answer (score 1):

You might **abuse** of [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) which returns the last biggest element contrary to `std::max_element`:

```
auto last_min_it = std::minmax_element(input.begin(), input.end(), std::greater<>{}).second;
```

I would  probably use reverse iterator with `std::min_element`, though:

```
auto min_rev_it = std::min_element(input.rbegin(), input.rend());
```