# How do I find the smallest number vector with repeated numbers?

Tags: c++, vector

I have this vector with these numbers `{0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3}` and I'm trying to use this approach to have the minimum number and its index:

```
int min_num = *min_element(nums.begin(), nums.end());
int min_num_idx = min_element(nums.begin(), nums.end()) - nums.begin();
```

However, this returns the first smallest number it found so the `0` in index `0`. Is there a way to make it return the last smallest number instead? (the `0` in index `2` instead)

Comment: Any restriction on complexity?

Comment: Why don't you just reverse the array and call min_element on that?

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53979284/c-stl-min-element

Answer (score 3):

> However, this returns the first smallest number it found so the 0 in index 0. Is there a way to make it return the last smallest number instead? (the 0 in index 2 instead)

You can try [`std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> n { 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator found_it = std::min_element(n.rbegin(), n.rend());
    if (found_it != n.rend()) {
        std::cout << "Minimum element: " << *found_it << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Minimum element index: " << std::distance(n.begin(), std::next(found_it).base()) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

> Output:
>
> Minimum element: 0
>
> Minimum element index: 2

Comment: `auto found_it = ...`

Comment: @bolov I explicitly mentioned it in order to demonstrate that the type returned by `std::min_element()` in this case is `std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator` and not `std::vector<int>::iterator`. But, sure you could let the compiler automatically deduce the type with `auto`.

Comment: fair enough, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
int min_num_idx = nums.size() - 1 - min_element(nums.rbegin(), nums.rend()) - nums.rbegin();
```